# Verificação de parâmetros no MVC

Tags: php, mvc

No Padrão MVC, o Model é o responsável pela camada de negócios, nele ficarão as regras de negócio e as validações.
Tenho uma dúvida sobre o seguinte. Um método no controller que recebe um parâmetro qualquer (pode ser um tipo primitivo ou um objeto). Ele chama o model para executar uma ação (como persistir no banco, alterar ou excluir).

A primeira dúvida: o Model deve esperar que o parâmetro esteja correto?
Ou seja, deve existir uma validação no controller para saber se o parâmetro veio corretamente ou deve-se passar o parâmetro para o Model como foi enviado para o controller e o Model deve fazer essa validação?

A segunda dúvida: se o Model fizer a validação do parâmetro como deve ser tratado o retorno?
Digamos que a ação seja inserir no banco de dados uma nova entidade. E que o padrão seja retornar o ID dessa entidade em caso de sucesso. Em caso de erro, o que seria a melhor decisão, retornar 0 como erro, lançar uma exception e retornar 0 ou seria melhor refatorar essas ações para que elas retornem algo que possa ser utilizado tanto em caso de sucesso como em caso de retorno?

Estou trabalhando num projeto feito em Silex com Doctrine DBAL, mas que não foi feito por mim e estou tendo estas dúvidas porque vejo que a aplicação não segue um fluxo correto e padronizado nessas situações.
Aqui mesmo o controller tem mais responsabilidade que o Model e isso tem me feito avaliar a refatoração.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O model deve cuidar, dentre outras coisas, de sua própria integridade. Ele deve fazer a validação e retornar o erro quando um método save() for invocado, por exemplo. O mais comum é que, ao tentar salvar um model com erro de validação, ele retorne um boolean (true/false).

Caberá ao controller encaminhar esse erro para que, de alguma forma, seja corrigido pelo usuário. O que fazer com o erro não é responsabilidade do model.

Respondendo às dúvidas:

*A primeira dúvida: o Model deve esperar que o parâmetro esteja correto? Ou seja, deve existir uma validação no controller para saber se o parâmetro veio corretamente ou deve-se passar o parâmetro para o Model como foi enviado para o controller e o Model deve fazer essa validação?*
**Não. Deve-se passar o parâmetro como foi enviado, o Model faz a validação e retorna para o controller para que o erro seja "encaminhado".**

*A segunda dúvida: se o Model fizer a validação do parâmetro como deve ser tratado o retorno? Digamos que a ação seja inserir no banco de dados uma nova entidade. E que o padrão seja retornar o ID dessa entidade em caso de sucesso. Em caso de erro, o que seria a melhor decisão, retornar 0 como erro, lançar uma exception e retornar 0 ou seria melhor refatorar essas ações para que elas retornem algo que possa ser utilizado tanto em caso de sucesso como em caso de retorno?* 
**Ao falhar em tentar salvar, o model deve retornar a informação suficiente para que o controller possa tratar o erro. Retornar false e um objeto/json com os atributos que falharam na validação é uma boa alternativa.**

abraço

Comment: Obrigado Adriano. Mas poderia editar sua resposta de forma mais clara. Tipo, seguindo um pouco as minhas dúvidas. Captei que o model deve ser independente mas não ficou totalmente claro as respostas para minhas dúvidas.

Comment: Editado ;) A resposta do colega @Papa Charlie pode te ajudar mais na implementação da solução. abraço

Comment: Muito obrigado @adriano-godoy. Ficou mais claro agora!

Answer (score 3):

Há muitas formas de se fazer.

Vou analisar uma possibilidade seguindo a proposta do @Adriano Godoy, não que esteja errada, mas é apenas simplista levando em conta um retorno bool em caso de falha ou sucesso. *Leia-se que não é uma critica, mas sim um complemento à resposta dada*.

> Na prática o *model* recebe `123` no campo *nome*, e verifica que não é um input tipo *AZ* e retorna false. Seu *controller* vai receber o bool como erro e avisar na *view* que o input está incorreto. O problema aqui seria como informar o erro ao usuário, supondo que você queira mostrar uma mensagem do tipo: **Seu nome deve conter apenas letras**. Seu modelo validou e retornou *false*, mas não informa o tipo de erro encontrado.

1) Você poderia trabalhar com um retorno em forma de array: `array( 'status' => false , 'campo_nome' => 'Seu nome deve conter apenas letras' )`, mas assim começa a perder o padrão.

2) Se o seu modelo trabalhar com uma instância de um *Validate*, o controller poderia receber o objeto e trabalhar as mensagens de erro.

`$model-> validate-> status = false`, seu controller teria acesso às mensagens de erro pertinentes aos campos de um formulário, por exemplo, e passaria para a view sem grandes problemas.

Toda *minha* validação e sanitização são feitas pelo controller e em caso de falha nem invocam o modelo. Minhas regras são abstraídas do modelo justamente para facilitar as validações e as mensagens no caso de internacionalização e regionalização (levando em conta os diferentes formatos de input). Mas esse é o **meu** caso e vários fatores foram levado em conta, mas algo mais simples pode ser feito como descrito acima.

---

O segundo caso é mais um padrão. Há quem só use as `exception` para tratamento de erro. Eu julgo que `exception` podem ser usadas visando a flexibilidade. Se você trabalhar com elas de forma correta não haverá problema. Mas há casos que um simples `bool` resolve.

Comment: Obrigado Papa Charlie. Foi esclarecedora sua resposta!